# Скорость работы dynamic в C#

Tags: c#, оптимизация, clr

Смотрю курсы по C# proffesional от ITVDN. Там пример, первый раз обращаются к полю dynamic, которое раннее приравнено к ссылке на объект, и показывают, что первое обращение к такому полю занимает 2 миллиона тиков. Я повторяю это на своем компьютере, но у меня всего 2 тысячи тиков. Примерно в 10 раз больше, чем следующие обращения к dynamic. Соль то в том, что dynamic запоминает объект, но в первый раз он ничего о нем не знает и поэтому занимает больше времени. Но 2 тысячи и 2 миллиона для одинаковых функций - очень большая разница. Может курс устарел и разработчики C# оптимизировали dynamic?
Код:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
dynamic d = c;
long start, end;

while (true)
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out start);
    d.m();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out end);
    Console.WriteLine((end - start) + '\n');
}
```

Comment: _Смотрю курсы по C# proffesional от ITVDN._ Немедленно прекратите! Видеокурсы — зло.

Comment: а что в этом коде происходит-то? переменная dynamic Не используется нигде

Comment: В цикле вместо c.m() должно быть d.m(). Опечатка. Я исправил, однако должного эффекта всеравно не получил. Теперь тиков 33 тысячи.

Comment: Ну так это хороший сигнал того, что вредно доверять левым видео из интернета. Практика — критерий истины. Кто знает, может эти дядьки для тестов использовали непрогретый метод, и в подсчёт попадала стоимость JIT-компиляции?

Comment: В том то и дело, что метод вызывается непрогретый(если я правильно понял), чтобы показать, что непрогретые методы занимают очень большое время. Так и есть. Но с примерно такими же результатами другого кода по времени, в видеокурсе - 2млн, у меня 2 тысячи. Вероятно .NET обновился, вот я и поинтересовался, может знает кто. Курсы на самом деле очень качественные и подробные.

Answer (score 5):

На вопрос о разнице в количестве тиков отвечать не буду, потому как неизвестны ни способ измерения, ни конфигурации вашего и автора курса компьютеров, ни версии .NET.

Вместо этого отвечу, почему первый вызов метода работает медленнее. Авось кому пригодится. Дополнения к посту приветствуются.

Для каждого выражения (операции), использующего объект типа `dynamic`, компилятор генерирует специальный объект под названием dynamic call site, который представляет это выражение (операцию). После компиляции приведенного в вопросе кода получается *примерно* следующее (код с измерением опустил):

```
static DynamicCallSite dCallSite;

...

MyClass c = new MyClass();
dynamic d = c;

while (true)
{
    if (dCallSite == null)
    {
        dCallSite = new DynamicCallSite();
    }
    dCallSite.DoInvocation("m", d);
}
```

При этом объект dynamic call site генерируется *только один раз* для каждого выражения. Это первая монетка в копилку "почему первый вызов работает медленнее".

Дальше DLR проверяет типа объекта `d`, обнаруживает, что это C# объект, и вызывает С# компилятор, который, используя метаданные, генерирует expression tree для данного выражения. Expression tree возвращается обратно DLR, компилируется, получившийся делегат вызывается и *кэшируется*. Т.е. если DLR в дальнейшем встретит такое же выражения для объекта такого же типа, будет вызван закэшированный делегат. Это вторая монетка в копилку "почему первый вызов работает медленнее".

Во время второго вызова у нас уже есть dynamic call site, так что DLR просто проверяет тип объекта, достает из кэша скомпилированный делегат и выполняет его.